# Rewritten mySQL Statement

Tags: mysql, formatting

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR('$uDate1'), week), ' Monday'), '%X%V %W') + 
    INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR('$uDate1'), week), ' Monday'), 
    '%X%V %W'))) DAY)
     as week_end_date
```

What this statement does is take the date I give it (**$uDate1**) and give me the week end date (**Saturday**) of that week. This works well and I am happy with it, kinda.

I was wondering if there were some things I missed that would either make this more efficient or even if I missed some shortcuts to this.

Any suggestions for me?

---

```
week >= WEEK('$uDate1') AND week <= WEEK('$uDate2')
```

This is in my WHERE clause. So basically if I use this...

```
DATE('$uDate1', INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK('$uDate1') DAY)
```

...then it returns the same day for all records. I need it to be able to go over a span of a few weeks.

---

I have a column in my database named 'week'. It simply stores an INT that corresponds to the week of the year. (ex. 21 for this week)

I then have two date picker boxes. The output gets the week end date based of each week that is BETWEEN and INCLUDES the days chosen.

**5/10/2016 & 5/26/2016** outputs **5/14/2016, 5/21/2016, 5/28/2016**

What gets exported to CSV file looks something like this..

```
WEEK END, LAST NAME, FIRST NAME, ...
5/10/2016, Smith, John, ...
5/26/2016, Jones, James, ...
```

It outputs anyone who had hours during the week, with the week end date.

SIDE NOTE: I do appreciate the comments and help. I don't want anyone to stress over this though! Just curious if better way. :)

Comment: imho you should move this conversion out of mysql at all. why don't you do that on php side?

Comment: What is `week`, and why are you concatenating it to the year? Why don't you just use `DAYOFWEEK('$uDate1')`?

Comment: week is the "week of the year number" stored in my database

Comment: What format is the date being passed in? If just a ccyy-mm-dd date then can't you just use _SELECT DATE_ADD($uDate1, INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK($uDate1) DAY)_

Comment: It is being passed in as yyyy-mm-dd. The statement works. I have it being passed in as it is stored in the database.

Comment: Your SQL seems massively complicated for what you are trying to do. My suggestion just takes the current date and adds to that 7 - the day of the week (day of the week of 7 = Saturday, so if a Sat takes no days from the date). Yours is taking the year, and adding the week of the year (I assume - should be _WEEK('$uDate1')_ I think), adding on the day and then changing that string back to a date the calculating that date again, finding its day of the week (which will ALWAYS be a Monday so 2), taking that from 7 (so ALWAYS 5) and adding that the the date you first calculated.

Comment: I am aware that it seems complicated. That is why I posted it on here, to see if there was a better way. :)

Comment: Could you make a simple example of what you were trying to explain?

Comment: Can you post the table declare of the table you are running against, a few rows of sample data and the output you want for those rows please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your current SQL is so complicated.

You say it is just to *take a date and give me the week end date (Saturday) of that week* .

How you are doing this at the moment is:-

- Yours is taking the year
- Adding the week of the year (I assume - should be WEEK('$uDate1') I think)
- Adding on the day as a string (so for example for today it would be *2016 21 Monday* )
- Changing that string back to a date a datetime value
- Converting that datetime value back to a date.
- Then taking the year again
- Adding the week of the year again
- Getting the day of the week of the resulting string. As you have concatenated    *Monday* on to the date then the day of the week will always be 2.
- Taking that resulting day of the week and subtracting it from 7. As the day of the week will always be 2 this will always result in 5
- Adding on the day as a string (so for example for today it would be *2016 21 Monday* ).
- This value is then added on to the previously calculated date, taking the Monday date and adding 5 days.

My suggestion was to just use:-

```
DATE_ADD($uDate1, INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK($uDate1) DAY)
```

which is far simpler, and appears to cover your requirements.

EDIT

Looking at your edit you want a list of all the Saturdays for weeks all or partially between 2 passed dates.

If so I think the following will do it and hopefully be more efficient as there is no need to translate dates to and from string. Note it relies on your week table to add to the date, hence only copes with date ranges of up to that many weeks.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('$uDate1', INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK('$uDate1') DAY), INTERVAL `week` WEEK) AS aDate
FROM `week`
HAVING aDate  BETWEEN '$uDate1' AND DATE_ADD('$uDate2', INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK('$uDate2') DAY)
ORDER BY aDate
```

Comment: I appreciate the post. I did originally have this. The problem is that it misses a main part of my statement. Ill edit my post to show some more details.

Comment: @lapaz - I have added a suggestion to get the range of dates. Hope it helps

Comment: That is perfect! I was hoping to get something shorter and cleaner than what I had. That was the whole point of this post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment you should move this transformation from mysql query to php code.

I see no reason to do this calculation on mysql side.

http://ideone.com/48zLvF

```
$week_day = intval(date('w',$uDate1));

if ($week_day<6) {
  $end_of_week = $uDate1+(86400*(6-$week_day));
} else {
  $end_of_week = $uDate1;
}
```

Comment: The reason that I have this in the statement is because I have it printing out to a CSV file using the select statement.

Comment: Also it does not seem to save me code or efficiency to do it in PHP vs MySQL